# Button Color On Face Detection- Android

Tags: android, android-studio, face-detection

I am changing color of a button on face detection. But the issue is as soon as face is detected. App crashes,

```
public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera c) {

    if (faces.length > 0) {
        Log.d("FaceDetection", "face detected X and Y are as: " + faces.length +
                " Face 1 Location X: " + faces[0].rect.centerX() +
                "Y: " + faces[0].rect.centerY());
        Button capture2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        capture2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else {

            Log.d("FaceDetection", "face detected X and Y are as: " + 0);
    }
    }
};
```

> Logcat

```
11-25 00:45:01.309 2529-2529/videocaptureexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1015)
11-25 00:45:01.309 2529-2529/videocaptureexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-25 00:45:01.309 2529-2529/videocaptureexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
11-25 00:45:01.309 2529-2529/videocaptureexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
11-25 00:45:01.309 2529-2529/videocaptureexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 00:45:01.309 2529-2529/videocaptureexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-25 00:45:01.309 2529-2529/videocaptureexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
11-25 00:45:01.309 2529-2529/videocaptureexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
11-25 00:45:01.309 2529-2529/videocaptureexample E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 00:45:03.164 2529-2529/videocaptureexample I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2529 SIG: 9
```

Comment: At least, we need to see the entire stacktrace. We don't even know what kind of exception it is.

Comment: Pasting Logcat is tedious work, as it needs to be indented/aigned. Is there a shortcut to paste it here?

Comment: Try a service like Gist or Pastebin